# Limit calculation with Riemann integral

Tags: integration, limits

Help me calculating the limit with Riemann integral:

$$a_n=\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n^2+1}}+\frac{2}{n\sqrt{n^2+4}}+\frac{3}{n\sqrt{n^2+9}}+...+\frac{n-1}{n\sqrt{n^2+(n-1)^2}}$$

Comment: Welcome to Math.StackExchange! You will find that you will find a lot more enthusiasm from users in helping you with your problem if you show your effort: what you have tried, what methods you think will help, what you guess might be the answer, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: This can be written as
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n} \sum_{r=1}^{n-1} \frac{r}{\sqrt{(n^2+r^2)}}$$
$$=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{r=1}^{n-1} \frac{\frac{r}{n}}{\sqrt{1+(\frac{r}{n})^2}}$$
$$=\int_0^1 \frac {xdx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$

Comment: The sum should be from $1$ to $n-1$ and these sums are not equal to the integral, rather their limit is.

Comment: @zhw. That is absolutely correct, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: btw I just noticed that $n$ isn't tending to infinity here, atleast it's not given in the problem, That would make the conversion of sigma to integral invalid as the limit is inapplicable...

Comment: "Help me please with calculate this limit " -- so you can assume it is the limit as $n\to \infty$

Answer (score 1):

Hint. For a continuous function $f$ on $[0,1]$ you have $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f\Big(\frac{k}{n}\Big) \rightarrow \int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx.$$